# ActiveRecord::PendingMigrationError (DEVISE ERROR) - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I tried to run http://localhost:3000/users/sign_up but it gives me this error:

```
ActiveRecord::PendingMigrationError
Migrations are pending. To resolve this issue, run: bin/rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development

Rails.root: c:/xampp/htdocs/pinteresting

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
activerecord (4.2.5) lib/active_record/migration.rb:392:in `check_pending!'
activerecord (4.2.5) lib/active_record/migration.rb:373:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `__run_callbacks__'
activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:778:in `_run_call_callbacks'
activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:78:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
web-console (2.2.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:39:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
railties (4.2.5) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (4.2.5) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
railties (4.2.5) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
```

This gives me a headache. I am new to rails and I make sure that i have everything set up correctly via devise gem. Now what am I going to do? Any help please?

I run `bin/rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development`

But it says 'bin' is not a recognized as internal or external command. Tried this before I ask.

Comment: read. the. error!!! :) `To resolve this issue, run: bin/rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development`

Comment: it says 'bin' is not a recognized as internal or external command. Tried this before I ask.

Comment: try `rake db:migrate`, as I've shown in answer

Comment: It says rake aborted!

StandardError: An error has occured, this and all later migrations cancelled:

SQLITE3:SQLException: no such table: users: ALTER TABLE 'users'

Comment: now it means you are trying to migrate on a table, which does not exist. If you do not have any valuable data in db, run rake `db:drop && rake db:create && rake db:migrate` (it will drop any data, recreate the database and run the migrations - should be fine, if everything is right

Comment: Permission denied...couldn't drop db:development.sqlite3

Comment: then you've installed gems/db wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Two slightly different ways you can call the same command:
`rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development` which drops the 'bin' element and should work anyway.

Or `bundle exec rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development` which uses bundle exec to run commands in the project.

Make sure you are running any commands like this from the right directory, the one you run `rails server` etc from at the root of your project.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
    ActiveRecord::Migrator.migrate("db/migrate/", nil)
```